# Close a window with child window and reopen it with Alt+Tab doesn't works correctly

Tags: cocoa

I've created a Window which contains a child Window. 
After i close the Main Window with `Cmd + W` (thus, losing the main/key window status) whenever i try to reopen it with `Cmd + Tab`, only the child window went displayed... not the main one.

Cmd + W command is bindend to  First Responder -> `performClose:` as usual... and the child window is added to the main window with:

```
[window addChildWindow:childWindow ordered:NSWindowAbove];
```

Why the child window is still visible after `Alt + Tab` ?

---Edit: I create this function that seems to resolve my situation .. but i'm not sure this is the right way:

```
-(IBAction)closeWindows:(id)sender{ 

    [[self window]close];
    NSArray *childWin = [[self window]childWindows];
    for(NSWindow *win in childWin){ 
        [win close];
    }
}
```

Comment: At the moment i write a function to close all window... i edit my question adding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functions works for me:

```
-(IBAction)closeWindows:(id)sender{ 

    [[self window]close];
    NSArray *childWin = [[self window]childWindows];
    for(NSWindow *win in childWin){ 
        [win close];
    }
}
```